# python3.7 pypi-server:SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: python, ssl, centos

I would like to deploy my blog(based in python3.7 and django2.0) into server(centos6.) and I made a virtual environment(based in python3.7). after installing pypi-sever,I run pypi-server in terminal for testing whether it works. Unfortunately, this command does't work.I found many methods including update openssl,setuptools and soon,but they doesn't work.

Can anyone advise on what else can I try??

```
    (pypi-env3) [root@edward pypi-env3]# pypi-server
[I 181029 20:18:20 __init__:29] Opening sqlite database: /root/virtual_path/pypi-env3/packages/metadata.db
[I 181029 20:18:20 __init__:35] Database initialized as '/root/virtual_path/pypi-env3/packages/metadata.db'. Checking migrations...
[I 181029 20:18:20 server:165] Init thread pool with 6 threads
[I 181029 20:18:20 server:194] Starting server http://127.0.0.1:8080/
[W 181029 20:18:25 iostream:1332] SSL Error on 9 ('151.101.108.223', 443): [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1045)
[E 181029 20:18:25 ioloop:638] Exception in callback functools.partial(<function wrap.<locals>.null_wrapper at 0x7fc60131ad08>, <tornado.concurrent.Future object at 0x7fc6013928d0>)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/root/virtual_path/pypi-env3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 605, in _run_callback
        ret = callback()
      File "/root/virtual_path/pypi-env3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 277, in null_wrapper
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/root/virtual_path/pypi-env3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 626, in _discard_future_result
        future.result()
      File "/root/virtual_path/pypi-env3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 238, in result
        raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
      File "<string>", line 4, in raise_exc_info
      File "/root/virtual_path/pypi-env3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1063, in run
        yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
      File "/root/virtual_path/pypi-env3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pypi_server/cache.py", line 194, in wrap_gen
        f = gen.throw(e)
      File "/root/virtual_path/pypi-env3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pypi_server/handlers/pypi/proxy/client.py", line 49, in packages
        (yield cls.XMLRPC.list_packages())
      File "/root/virtual_path/pypi-env3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pypi_server/cache.py", line 189, in wrap_gen
        res = yield f
      File "/root/virtual_path/pypi-env3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1055, in run
        value = future.result()
      File "/root/virtual_path/pypi-env3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 238, in result
        raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
      File "<string>", line 4, in raise_exc_info
      File "/root/virtual_path/pypi-env3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1063, in run
        yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
      File "/root/virtual_path/pypi-env3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado_xmlrpc/client.py", line 111, in _remote_call
        response = yield self.client.fetch(req)
      File "/root/virtual_path/pypi-env3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1055, in run
        value = future.result()
      File "/root/virtual_path/pypi-env3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 238, in result
        raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
      File "<string>", line 4, in raise_exc_info
      File "/root/virtual_path/pypi-env3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 316, in wrapped
        ret = fn(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/root/virtual_path/pypi-env3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 289, in <lambda>
        future, lambda future: callback(future.result()))
      File "/root/virtual_path/pypi-env3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 238, in result
        raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
      File "<string>", line 4, in raise_exc_info
      File "/root/virtual_path/pypi-env3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1063, in run
        yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
      File "/root/virtual_path/pypi-env3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/tcpclient.py", line 189, in connect
        server_hostname=host)
      File "/root/virtual_path/pypi-env3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1055, in run
        value = future.result()
      File "/root/virtual_path/pypi-env3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 238, in result
        raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
      File "<string>", line 4, in raise_exc_info
      File "/root/virtual_path/pypi-env3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/iostream.py", line 1315, in _do_ssl_handshake
        self.socket.do_handshake()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 1108, in do_handshake
        self._sslobj.do_handshake()
    ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1045)
```